# How to fix Qt application that does not work with proc/stat system file in linux

Tags: c++, qt5

I'm writing some Qt application for read cpu/memory states. However, appears a some error: Cannot open proc/stat device. Application is crashed. Please tell me where is problem ? Bellow i will also provide a piece of code.

```
QVector<qulonglong> SysInfoLinuxImpl::cpuRawData()
{
    QFile file("proc/stat");
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QByteArray line = file.readLine();
    file.close();
    qulonglong totalUser = 0, totalUserNice = 0, totalSystem = 0, totalIdle = 0;
    std::sscanf(line.data(), "cpu %llu %llu %llu %llu", &totalUser, &totalUserNice, &totalSystem, &totalIdle);
    QVector<qulonglong> rawData;
    rawData.append(totalUser);
    rawData.append(totalUserNice);
    rawData.append(totalSystem);
    rawData.append(totalIdle);
    return rawData;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I've included code changes, also does not work. However, when I start it from the command line with the command cat stat from exactly folder, the program working. I am think in Qt frameworks is something wrong ?!

Comment: This depends on how it _does not work_. Could you explain in more detail? Does it fail to open `"/proc/stat"`?

Comment: Yes, /proc/stat/ not does not work in application. I can not find how. I would try to insert the c++ stl library instead of qt to work with files, maybe then it succeeds.

Comment: The `QFile` is only a wrapper for the I/O functions of C library or OS API. (I tried to find the resp. source code on woboq.org but it's engine based and I gave up. You may dig deeper if interested.) However, if you can get it working with C++ or C I/O functions, then I would agree with your doubt about a broken Qt installation. File access permissions could be an issue as well although I'm not sure why reading of `/proc/stat` should be prohibited.

Comment: I am find some interesting when debugging: can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `SysInfoWidget', but i have override correctly so, something wrong is in Qt. I'll have to investigate further. Thanks again for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

The code exposed by OP has various flaws where it may fail:

1. `QFile file("proc/stat");` tries to open `proc/stat` in the current directory. If this isn't accidentally the root directory it might not open what OP expects or just fail.
   This should be replaced with `QFile file("/proc/stat");` which opens an absolute path (independent of current directory).
2. The success of `file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);` isn't tested. [`QFile::open()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#open) has return type `bool` and

   > returning true if successful; otherwise false.

   This should be checked.
3. The success of `std::sscanf(line.data(), "cpu %llu %llu %llu %llu", &totalUser, &totalUserNice, &totalSystem, &totalIdle);` isn't checked as well. [`std::sscanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf#Return_value) has return type `int` and returns

   > Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned (which may be zero in case a matching failure occurred before the first receiving argument was assigned), or EOF if input failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned.

I turned the sample code of OP into an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and added some diagnostics to demonstrate the issues:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

namespace SysInfoLinuxImpl {

template <bool FIX = false>
QVector<qulonglong> cpuRawData();

} // namespace SysInfoLinuxImpl

template <bool FIX = false>
QVector<qulonglong> SysInfoLinuxImpl::cpuRawData()
{
  QFile file(FIX ? "/proc/stat" : "proc/stat");
  file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
  QByteArray line = file.readLine();
  file.close();
  qDebug() << "line:" << line;
  qulonglong totalUser = 0, totalUserNice = 0, totalSystem = 0, totalIdle = 0;
  int ret =
  std::sscanf(line.data(), "cpu %llu %llu %llu %llu", &totalUser, &totalUserNice, &totalSystem, &totalIdle);
  qDebug() << "sscanf(): " << ret;
  qDebug() << "totalUser:    " << totalUser;
  qDebug() << "totalUserNice:" << totalUserNice;
  qDebug() << "totalSystem:  " << totalSystem;
  qDebug() << "totalIdle:    " << totalIdle;
  QVector<qulonglong> rawData;
  rawData.append(totalUser);
  rawData.append(totalUserNice);
  rawData.append(totalSystem);
  rawData.append(totalIdle);
  return rawData;
}

int main()
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  // check original code
  qDebug() << "with 'proc/stat'";
  SysInfoLinuxImpl::cpuRawData();
  // check fixed code
  qDebug() << "with '/proc/stat'";
  SysInfoLinuxImpl::cpuRawData<true>();
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled and tested the code on [cygwin](http://cygwin.org) (I'm on Windows 10) and got the following output:

```
Qt Version: 5.9.4
with 'proc/stat'
QIODevice::read (QFile, "proc/stat"): device not open
line: ""
sscanf():  -1
totalUser:     0
totalUserNice: 0
totalSystem:   0
totalIdle:     0
with '/proc/stat'
line: "cpu 137982341 0 106654637 1152709669\n"
sscanf():  4
totalUser:     137982341
totalUserNice: 0
totalSystem:   106654637
totalIdle:     1152709669
```

Finally, I'm not quite sure why OP claims that

> Application is crashed.

I strongly believe that the crash doesn't occur in the exposed code (but somewhere else). I think so because:

1. `QByteArray line = file.readLine();` (when tries to read from `file` which failed to open) results in an empty array ([`QIODevice::readLine()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readLine), [`QByteArray`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#details)) but even an empty array *always ensures that the data is followed by a '\0' terminator*.
2. Hence, the access to `line.data()` in `std::sscanf(line.data(), "cpu %llu %llu %llu %llu", &totalUser, &totalUserNice, &totalSystem, &totalIdle);` should be safe even if none of the variables are assigned. The variables in turn are initialized and have defined values even if `sscanf()` failed.
3. The final calls of `rawData.append()` might potentially allocate memory which may fail but, again, I don't see what might crash here.

So, I haven't any clue what of this code may crash except that other, previously executed code caused [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior/4105123#4105123) which accidentally starts to become visible in the exposed code.